# Run a PHP script on click of a button?

Tags: php

I have a php file which I want be executed when I click on a button. I have been using the following code to achieve the same:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="Run Script" name="submit">
</form>
```

The code seems to take me to test.php file, but I want to be redirected back to the page where I was. Can is be possible to run this test.php on click on a button and not get redirected? Something like running the script in background?

Please let me know if you guys need further clarification.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You need to Google: Ajax

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use AJAX

```
<script>
function doTheFunction(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","URL_OF_PHP_FILE",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>



     <button onclick"doTheFunction();">Run the script</button>
```

Comment: did you handle it with the php file? "URL_OF_PHP_FILE" should include something that handles $_GET requests

Comment: or you can edit it to handle $_POST instead, edit the xmlhttp.open from GET to POST and handle the data as $_POST

Comment: I used the POST method and it worked.. thanks Ehab. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an [ajax call](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) and prevent the forms submit.

Html:

```
<form onsubmit="return doAxajCall();"> </form>
```

js Code:

```
function doAjaxCall(){
    //do ajax call however you want
    return false; //prevents the form from submitting
}
```

Comment: Im not sure, how to do an AJAX call. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way;

Make the action of your form 'self' like this;

```
<form  action="#" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Do PHP">
</form>
```

Then test for submission at the top of the page like this;

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // do stuff

}
```

in your instance 'test.php' has to included in the original file.

Answer (score 0):

at the bottom of you php file

```
header('Location: lastPage.php');
```

or do some tricks using `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
<!-- including jquery.min.js cdn -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" value="Run Script" id="submit" name="submit" />

<!-- now set ajax call for button -->
<script> 
   $("#submit").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:'test.php',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response){
           alert('test.php file executed');
        }
      });
   });

</script>
```